# Cannot access all backbone model attributes from template

Tags: backbone.js

The problem I am trying to debug is that, in my backbone view, all the model attributes (name, id, email etc) are available, (I have console.log() the model attributes to verify this), however, when I render the view passing the model, only the name attribute is available in the template, all other attributes are undefined,please is there any thing I am missing, as this is my first backbone application and I have spent hours trying to debug this and have gone through many tutors online and my code seems correct, thanks

//BACKbone view  method(I have verified and all the model values are available here)

```
var profileView=Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('#content'),

    initialize:function(){
      this.model.bind('change',this.render,this);
    },

    render:function(){

        var self=this;

        this.$el.html(_.template(profileTemplate,this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
```

//HTML TEMPLATE (profileTemplate), only the name attribute is available in the template, //browser gives an error of 'undefined' for all other attributes except the name attribute

```
<h1><%=name.first%> <%=name.last%> </h1>//displays correctly
<%=email%> //undefined
```

//SCHEMA

```
 var AccountSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{type:String,unique:true},
    password:{type:String},
    name:{
        first:{type:String},
        last:{type:String},
      full:{type:String}
    },

  });
```

//IT IS SOLVED NOW, IT happened because I executed the fetch command on the model after calling the render method instead of before calling the render method

This is my router, I call the model.fetch() from the router after the view is created. The problem stopped when I called model.fetch() before the rendering of the before

```
define([''views/profile''],function(,ProfileView){

  var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    currentView: null, 

    socketEvents: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),

    routes: {
      'addcontact': 'addcontact',
      'index': 'index',
      'login': 'login',
      'register': 'register',
      'forgotpassword': 'forgotpassword',
      'profile/:id': 'profile',
      'contacts/:id': 'contacts',
       "upload/:id":"upload"
    },
    profile: function(id) {
      var model = new Account({id:id});
      console.log('profile user:'+id);
      this.changeView(new ProfileView({model:model})); //View is created here
      model.fetch(); // model is fetched after view is rendered, cause for the problem in my case
    }
  });

  return new router();
});
```

Comment: I get [Object, Object] when I console.log(this.model.toSON());

Comment: I tried  console.log(this.model.get('email')); etc, for each of the attributes, from the backbone view and they are present, but they arent in the html template

Comment: Thanks or the reply, its ok now, it happened because I was executing the fect command after I called the render method

Comment: Please post your own answer and accept it so the question shows as resolved.

Comment: I am having this same issue, can you please provide further details so that i may solve it ! Thanks