# How to access unrelated attributes in ruby views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js

I am new to ruby on rails. I have a boards model and its views. I have a category model and its views as well. The relation between category and board is one to many i.e.  one category has many boards. My requirement is to access category id placed in boards table and show respective category titles for that particular category id. At label tag `<label for="home"><%= board.category_id %></label>` i am getting empty category id in my label tag or may be a null. On rails console it is giving me data properly.
This is a code for view.

```html
<div class="myNavigation">
  <nav class="vertical">
    <ul>
      <% boards.each(function (board) { %>  
        <li>
          <label for="home"><%= board.category_id %></label>
          <input type="radio" checked="true" name="verticalMenu" id="home" />
          <div>
            
          </div>
        </li>
      <% }); %>  
    </ul>
  </nav>
  </div>
```

> Board Model Class:

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :open, :members, :category_id
  #attr_accessor :category_id
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :board_activities , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :boards_members, class_name: "BoardMember" , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :boards_members , dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category, class_name: "category"

end
```

> Category Model Class

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :description
    #attr_accessor :category_id
    has_many :boards, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Kindly also suggest easy way to create ruby partial layouts i.e. application.erb can be included in some pages and in some it should not. And it should also get above mentioned category id in which it is included.

As a side note i am working in backbone rails, above view is actually a boards template. I am working with ruby 2.2.1 version and 4.1.2 rails version. Further details can also be provided. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the view code, your loop over boards should look like this:

```
<% boards.each do |board| %>  
  <li>
    <label for="home"><%= board.category_id %></label>
    <input type="radio" checked="true" name="verticalMenu" id="home" />
    <div>

    </div>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

It looks like the code you have is just declaring anonymous functions inside the loop, I'm not sure - but I think this is what you want :)

Comment: I am sorry, it crashes my front end. Nothing is displaying with this loop. I have mentioned I am using this in backbone template.

Comment: oh my mistake, I didn't see your note, I thought it was a plain rails view file - I'm not very familiar with backbone, can't help you there

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<%= board.category.title %>` instead of `<%= board.category_id %>`

If you really can have a null category_id, you could make it:

```
<%= board.category.title if board.category_id %>
```

Comment: I am sorry, this is also not working, do you need more explanation sir ?

Comment: Actually my problem is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386090/cannot-access-all-backbone-model-attribues-from-template I am not getting how to do it ! Can you help me out !

Comment: Yeah, this is potentially a problem in passing your model to the backbone view. Would need to see a lot more of your template, router, etc. to debug. (where you are calling fetch, render, etc.) are you getting any errors?

Comment: Sir i have a posted a separate thread you can answer there as well i will accept your both answers surely :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458539/unable-to-access-backbone-nested-attributes